# Toast expirationTime in Javascript in Universal Windows Platform (UWP) doesn't work

Tags: javascript, uwp

I set the toast expirationTime after 30 seconds. I expected the toast will disappears after 30 seconds but it disappears after about 5-10 seconds. Here is my code:

```
var toast = new notifications.ToastNotification(toastXml);
var currentTime = new Date();
toast.expirationTime = new Date(currentTime.getTime() + 30 * 1000);
var toastNotifier = notifications.ToastNotificationManager.createToastNotifier();
toastNotifier.show(toast);
```

Comment: I tested your code and the toast notification is disappearing from action center exactly after 30 seconds.

Comment: By "disappearing" - do you mean disappearing from action center or the time in which the toast notification hides itself in the action center? because all toasts will be minimized to action center in 5 seconds you cannot change that.

Comment: I mean toast notification like this : https://www.dropbox.com/s/7q3zht23nmm9vdi/Screenshot_41.png?dl=0 
Does it disappear exactly after 30 seconds?

Comment: Yup, in 5 seconds it gets minimized to action center and in 30 seconds it gets expired

Comment: @DaniAkash it's so strange that in the c# sample, the toast live for 30 seconds before minimized https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/Notifications/cs

Comment: Could you share more detail, such as  `toastXml`?